# Markdown to HTML Converter

Tags: python, markdown

I'm working on a markdown-to-html parser for my C++ proposals. Example usage is turning markdown like [this](https://github.com/BRevzin/cpp_proposals/blob/ab21fddc78ae92823915d86e789cfde71e833a36/md/sb-extensions.md) into an html page like [this](https://rawgit.com/brevzin/cpp_proposals/ab21fddc78ae92823915d86e789cfde71e833a36/1061_sb_pack/p1061r0.html). The part that caused me the most frustration was having (a) tables that (b) themselves can internally use markdown. I ended up with a hacky solution that happens to work right now (basically, recursively re-invoking `markdown` while doing my own HTML... "parsing"), but I'm very unsatisfied with it and would love to hear feedback on it. There's also other things I'm doing with `markdown` that can certainly be improved upon. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/BRevzin/cpp_proposals/blob/ab21fddc78ae92823915d86e789cfde71e833a36/md/better_md.py).

`toc` is basically a copy of `markdown.extensions.toc` with some minor changes - I wanted an ordered list and the section number to be included in the name (which I couldn't do without... copying it all).

```
import argparse
import json
import os
import sys

import markdown
from markdown.extensions import Extension
from markdown.extensions.codehilite import CodeHiliteExtension
from markdown.inlinepatterns import LinkPattern, LINK_RE, BacktickPattern, BACKTICK_RE
from markdown.treeprocessors import Treeprocessor
from markdown.postprocessors import Postprocessor
from markdown.preprocessors import Preprocessor
from markdown.util import etree, string_type, isBlockLevel, AtomicString
from toc import TocExtension

def local_path(filename):
    return os.path.join(sys.path[0], filename)

class LinkSaver(LinkPattern):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LinkSaver, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.markdown.saved_links = []

    def handleMatch(self, m):
        self.markdown.saved_links.append(m.group(9))
        return super(LinkSaver, self).handleMatch(m)

class RefProcessor(Treeprocessor):
    def __init__(self, md):
        super(RefProcessor, self).__init__(md)

        self.wg21 = json.load(open(local_path('index.json')))
        for key in sorted(self.wg21, reverse=True):
            if key.startswith('P') and key[:5] not in self.wg21:
                self.wg21[key[:5]] = self.wg21[key]

    def run(self, doc):
        wg21_links = []
        for link in self.markdown.saved_links:
            if 'wg21.link' in link:
                wg21_links.append(link.split('/')[-1].upper())

        if sorted(wg21_links):
            refs = etree.SubElement(doc, 'h1')
            refs.text = 'References'

            ul = etree.SubElement(doc, 'ul')
            for link in sorted(wg21_links):
                info = self.wg21[link]
                li = etree.SubElement(ul, 'li')
                a = etree.SubElement(li, 'a')
                a.attrib["href"] = info['long_link']
                a.text = '[{}]'.format(link)

                desc = etree.SubElement(li, 'span')
                desc.attrib['style'] = "margin-left: 5px;"
                desc.text = '"{}" by {}, {}'.format(
                    info['title'],
                    info['author'],
                    info['date'])

class TableCodeBlockProcessor(Preprocessor):
    def run(self, lines):
        new_lines = []
        to_markup = []
        target = new_lines

        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith('<th') or line.startswith('<td'):
                new_lines.append(line)
                target = to_markup
            elif line.startswith('</th') or line.startswith('</td'):
                target = new_lines
                new_lines.extend(
                    self.markdown.convert(u'\n'.join(to_markup))
                        .replace('<pre class="codehilite">',
                            '<pre style="background:transparent;border:0px">')
                        .split('\n'))
                to_markup = []
                new_lines.append(line)
            else:
                target.append(line)
        return new_lines

class CppBacktickPattern(BacktickPattern):
    def handleMatch(self, m):
        if m.group(4):
            text = m.group(4).strip()
            el = etree.Element('code')
            if text.startswith('#!'):
                el.text = AtomicString(text[2:].strip())
            else:
                el.attrib["class"] = "language-cpp"
                el.text = AtomicString(text.strip())
            return el
        else:
            return super(CppBacktickPattern, self).handleMatch(m)

class CppBacktickExtension(Extension):
    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        md.inlinePatterns[u'backtick'] = CppBacktickPattern(BACKTICK_RE)

class RefExtension(Extension):
    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        md.inlinePatterns[u'link'] = LinkSaver(LINK_RE, md)
        md.treeprocessors.add("refs", RefProcessor(md), '<toc')

class TableCodeBlockExtension(Extension):
    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        md.preprocessors.add("tbl_codeblock",
            TableCodeBlockProcessor(
                markdown.Markdown(extensions=[CodeHiliteExtension(use_pygments=False),
                    CppBacktickExtension()
                    ])
            ),
            '_begin')

def main(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Markdown formatter for papers')
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', dest='input', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', dest='output', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
        default='-')
    parser.add_argument('--style', default=local_path('style.html'),
        type=argparse.FileType('r'))
    parser.add_argument('--references', action='store_true')

    args = parser.parse_args(argv)

    write = args.output.write

    extensions = [CodeHiliteExtension(use_pygments=False),
        TocExtension(baselevel=2, anchorlink=False, title=None, marker=''),
        'markdown.extensions.meta',
        CppBacktickExtension(),
        TableCodeBlockExtension()]
    if args.references:
        extensions.append(RefExtension())

    md = markdown.Markdown(extensions=extensions)
    in_md = args.input.read().decode('utf-8')
    html = md.convert(in_md).replace('language-c++', 'language-cpp')
    write('<html>\n')
    write('<head>\n')
    write('<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n')
    write('<title>{}</title>\n'.format(md.Meta['title'][0]))
    write(args.style.read())
    write('\n</head>\n')
    write('<body>\n')
    write('<address align=right>\n')    
    write('Document Number: {} <br />\n'.format(md.Meta['document-number'][0]))
    write('Date: {} <br />\n'.format(md.Meta['date'][0]))
    write('Audience: {} <br />\n'.format(md.Meta['audience'][0]))
    write('Reply-To: {} <br />\n'.format('<br />'.join(md.Meta['authors'])))
    write('</address>\n')
    write('<hr /><h1 align=center>{}</h1>\n'.format(md.Meta['title'][0]))
    write('<h2>Contents</h2>\n')
    write('{}\n{}\n</html>'.format(md.toc, html.encode('utf-8')))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, yes I know, this *really* needs a *lot* of comments.

Comment: BTW, you do know that programs like [`pandoc`](https://pandoc.org/) already have this functionality, right?

Comment: @Graipher No, I didn't. Thanks for the tip, will look into it!